# query specific fields by document type

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently getting started with Elasticsearch and I am trying to build a search query that looks for a keyword in different fields, dependent on the document type.

> Example:
>
> Index Name: index1
>
> Document types:
>
> - doc1 (_id, name, size, color, weight)
> - doc2 (_id, name, duration, length, width, height)

Now I want to query `index1` for documents of types `doc1` and `doc2`, but in`doc1` I only want to search in columns `name`, `size` and `weight`, whilst in `doc2` I want to search in columns `name`, `length` and `height`.

How can I achieve this in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the fields by type and name and use a bool query. A basic example is below.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {
                   "bool": {
                       "must": [
                          {
                              "term": {
                                 "doc1.name": {
                                    "value": "2"
                                 }
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              "term": {
                                 "doc1.size": {
                                    "value": "23"
                                 }
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              "term": {
                                 "doc1.weight": {
                                    "value": "52"
                                 }
                              }
                          }
                       ]
                   }
               },
               {
                   "bool": {
                       "must": [
                          {
                               "term": {
                                 "doc2.name": {
                                    "value": "2"
                                 }
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              "term": {
                                 "doc2.length": {
                                    "value": "23"
                                 }
                              }
                          },
                          {
                              "term": {
                                 "doc2.height": {
                                    "value": "52"
                                 }
                              }
                          }
                       ]
                   }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```